# How to create temporary files in memory visible for other process, using python

Tags: python, memory, temporary-files

I'm trying to write simple batch file generator in python. Batch file consist of about 30-50 lines of text and is passed to other applications. During the execution of script there a lot of calls to external applications. I want to create file in memory (like named pipes in win32). Is there any platform-independent way?

UPD:
Thanks for suggestions. Finally decided to use sockets for message passing between applications using [cogen](http://code.google.com/p/cogen/).

Comment: On *nix systems you can create an in-memory file system. On Windows you have fewer options. Although ... why not just use system clipboard for Windows? You can stick multiple items in there.

Comment: Windows does have its own version of a pipe, but I think it is a pain.

Comment: Yes there are many issues to create and manage files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running a separate server, I'd use Memcached. It's very simple to use and very robust.

http://memcached.org/